# Do we know anything about DareDevil's (Matt Murdock's) Mother from the comics continuity?

Tags: marvel, comics, daredevil

In most continuities, Matt Murdock, prior to becoming the super hero DareDevil, was raised by a well-meaning, boxer single father, "Battling" Jack" aka "The Fighting Devil" Murdock. Little is ever really said about his relationship with his mother. In the first *DareDevil* film, his father Jack's death was a major push towards Matt becoming a hero, even taking inspiration for his hero name from his father's boxing name.

Granted, dead or missing parents are a major inspiration trope for vigilante-type heroes (Batman, Spider-Man, Ghost Rider, etc), but we're often given a *little* background on them.

Are there any stories regarding his mom, or maybe both of his parents, but his mother pecifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. [Maggie Murdock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggie_Murdock#:%7E:text=Margaret%20Grace%20%22Maggie%22%20Murdock%20is,the%20superhero%20known%20as%20Daredevil.), otherwise known as Sister Maggie, has had a pretty decent arc about her. Here's the first few paragraphs on Wikipedia:

> Sister Maggie (Maggie Murdock, née Maggie Grace) is the mother of Matthew Murdock, aka Daredevil. She and Jack had Matt when they were a young couple, but Maggie soon suffered from postpartum depression, having doubts, feeling constantly anxious regarding Matt's safety, thoughts which soon developed into self-loathing, feeling estranged, as she considered herself to be a bad mother; eventually her depression led to paranoia which was revealed to be post-natal depression. She began losing control of herself and started thinking that Jack was plotting against her, and that Matt was there to tear them apart. One night, under the influence of her mental illness, Maggie tried to assault the baby. Jack managed to stop her; Maggie broke down and hugged her husband not knowing what to do with her illness that she brought to the family. As soon as she came to her senses, she finally realized that she needed to leave for her husband and son's sakes. She soon packed her bags and ran from home, where she was taken in by a church, becoming a nun and started going by Sister Margaret. With the help of doctors and counseling, she recovered from her depression. She never came back to the Murdock residence because she didn't want to take the chance of threatening them again.
>
> As an adult, Matt reunited with Maggie during a time when Kingpin, having learned that Matt was Daredevil, engineered the ruin of his life on several levels. Nearly broken after trying to get revenge, Murdock was taken in by Sister Maggie and with his enhanced senses, immediately felt the connection between them but he never knew that she was his mother. However, when he asked her flatly if she was his mother, Maggie calmly smiled and denied this but in her heart she couldn't believe that she had a reunion with her son but didn't know how to tell him the truth. Matt, who had 'read' Maggie's reaction to his question with his abilities, knew she was lying, but not why. During this period of recovery, Maggie also briefly met Matt's friend and ally, Spider-Man, who was shocked by how broken Matt was. For some time after, Maggie was a figure in Matt's life.
>
> Years later, while caring for a baby girl he suspected of being the Antichrist, he almost threw the baby off the roof of building trying to kill it but soon realized he was wrong and plunged off the roof, saving her and himself, ending up in front of the Church where Sister Maggie lived. Daredevil brought her to Sister Maggie at the Clinton Mission Shelter and slept for two days in her room. While he slept, she cleaned his costume and cared for the infant. When Matt woke up, Maggie greeted him and offered him some food. After talking, Matt got her to finally admit that she was his mother. She noted the similarities between him and his father, but told him she had no answers for why she had left him so many years before. When he questioned all the problems he had had in life and told her that God had let her off pretty easily, she slapped him across the face, and he dropped to his knees and apologized. They talked for hours about Maggie's life before becoming a nun, she then encouraged him to ask God for answers about the baby, telling him that after all of his experiences in the supernatural that he should have no problem believing in God. He questioned how she could be so confident in her faith, and she told him a story about a knight and a monk. Maggie then advised Matt to talk to Karen Page, who was waiting for him downstairs in the sanctuary.

Comment: When did this story come out? Are they still close?

Comment: Daredevil Vol #1, Issues 229-233ish is when her basic story was introduced, Which looks to have been published in 1986. The "Antichrist baby" storyline was around 1999. Honestly, she doesn't show up too often in the books, mainly as an occasional plot device, so I suspect they're not that close what with her never really explaining to Matt why she gave him up (and not admitting to be his mother until that 1999 storyline).

Comment: Hmm.... lots of unresolved parental issues there. Well, at least Matt still has that connection to her now. Thank you soooooo much for clearing this up; I'll grab a look at those issues.